# Wrong intuition with partial derivatives.

Tags: intuition, fake-proofs

So I noticed I have some wrong intuition about partial derivatives and I would appreciate someone correcting me why I am wrong.  Say we have a function $f(x,y)=2\sqrt{xy}$. Clearly $f_x(x,y)$ decreases when x increases and $f_y(x,y)$ decreases when y increases. Now my intuition was telling me that this has to mean that every partial derivative in the direction that increases $x$ and $y$ should also decrease. However, if we consider $f(x,x)=2x$ this function actually increases at a constant rate when both $x$ and $y=x$ increase. I thought this since we know that partial in any direction is $<f_x,f_y>\cdot u$ where u is the unit vector of the direction. But then a linear combination of decreasing functions, is decreasing, right? This seems to contradict the fact that $f(x,x)=2x$

So where is my blunder? Why was I wrong?

thank you

Comment: (You mean $f(x,x) = 2x$)

Comment: Ah yes, my bad.

Comment: The partial derivative tells you how the function behaves if you advance *parallel to the corresponding axis*. So the fact that $f_{x}(x,y)$ decreases when $x$ increases tells you that if you advance **horizontally** then the function decreases as you move forward. $f_y(x,y)$ decreasing when $y$ increases tells you that if you advance **vertically** then the function decreases as $y$ increases. But these two don't tell you how the function behaves if you advance *diagonally* (along $x=y$). The behavior there can be independent of the behavior in the other directions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well they tell you the behaviour is a linear combination of the two, can you not conclude anything from that?

Comment: Oops; sorry. The function doesn't decrease: the derivative is positive, so the function is increasing. The derivative is decreasing....

Comment: The problem here is that the partial derivatives have mixed behaviors: $f_x(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}}$ decreases in the $x$ direction, but **increases** in the $y$ direction. And $f_y(x,y)$ decreases in the $y$ direction, but **increases** in the $x$ direction. If you try to argue mentally that going along $x=y$ is like going first horizontally and then vertically, you are mixing those two behaviors in each step.